# Fullcalendar showing 1 hour events as 2 hours

Tags: java, fullcalendar

I have the following JSON data:

2015-02-22T04:00:00-05:00 which clearly shows 4am to 5am which is a one hour slot, but in the week agenda view in fullcalendar it is showing as 4am to 6am, as are all 1 hour slots. any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What is happening between the JSON and your view?

Comment: A php file queries a database and outputs JSON.

Comment: @ElliottCoe That does not show 4am-5am. That is a single time that is offset -5 hours from GMT. You need to provide an `end` time. Change that `-05:00` to `-07:00` and you will see it will no longer be 4am on your calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mikesmithdev answered this one for me, I didn't have an end specified, I thought you could do it with just one string of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version (2.2.6) of the fullcalendar. For some reason this version works fine.

Please refer to this example: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oo4t7fzy/1/)

And here's a sample code that works properly and might help you as well:

```
var events_array = [
{
title: 'Test1',
start: moment('2015-02-03T05:00:00'),
end : moment('2015-02-03T12'),
tip: 'Test1'},
];
...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: events_array,
timezone : 'local',
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.attr('title', event.tip);
}
});
```